# Flutter package lateintialization error - '_image' has not been initialized

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to make the image_editor_pro package in flutter to work using their example, but when I run the app, I get a lateintialization error '_image' has not been initialized , I tried replacing `late` with `?` , but then I got another error since File type can't allow null values

The code :

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:image_editor_pro/image_editor_pro.dart';
import 'package:firexcode/firexcode.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return HomePage().xMaterialApp();
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  late File _image;

  Future<void> getimageditor() =>
      Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
        return ImageEditorPro(
          appBarColor: Colors.black87,
          bottomBarColor: Colors.black87,
          pathSave: null,
        );
      })).then((geteditimage) {
        if (geteditimage != null) {
          setState(() {
            _image = geteditimage;
          });
        }
      }).catchError((er) {
        print(er);
      });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return condition(
            condtion: _image == null,
            isTrue: 'Open Editor'.text().xRaisedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                getimageditor();
              },
            ).toCenter(),
            isFalse:
                _image == null ? Container() : Image.file(_image).toCenter())
        .xScaffold(
            appBar: 'Image Editor Pro example'.xTextColorWhite().xAppBar(),
            floatingActionButton:
                Icons.add.xIcons().xFloationActiobButton(color: Colors.red));
  }
}

Widget condition(
    {required bool condtion, required Widget isTrue, required Widget isFalse}) {
  return condtion ? isTrue : isFalse;
}
```

Comment: Make it nullable, then before using the File place a null check. You might need a "!" in places, when you checked for _images not being null before. I don´t think the late keyword is the right approach, because the user could cancle the image selection, leaving you with a null error (unless you assign a default value, which would be strange here)

Comment: Could you please explain where should I put `!`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `late File _image;` you can use `File? _image`; which makes the _image variable **nullable** with default value `null`. Make sure to have proper null checks like `(_image != null )` or `(image?.method)`

Full Code

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:image_editor_pro/image_editor_pro.dart';
import 'package:firexcode/firexcode.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return HomePage().xMaterialApp();
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  File? _image;

  Future<void> getimageditor() =>
      Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
        return ImageEditorPro(
          appBarColor: Colors.black87,
          bottomBarColor: Colors.black87,
          pathSave: null,
        );
      })).then((geteditimage) {
        if (geteditimage != null) {
          setState(() {
            _image = geteditimage;
          });
        }
      }).catchError((er) {
        print(er);
      });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return condition(
            condtion: _image == null,
            isTrue: 'Open Editor'.text().xRaisedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                getimageditor();
              },
            ).toCenter(),
            isFalse:
                _image == null ? Container() : Image.file(_image).toCenter())
        .xScaffold(
            appBar: 'Image Editor Pro example'.xTextColorWhite().xAppBar(),
            floatingActionButton:
                Icons.add.xIcons().xFloationActiobButton(color: Colors.red));
  }
}

Widget condition(
    {required bool condtion, required Widget isTrue, required Widget isFalse}) {
  return condtion ? isTrue : isFalse;
}
```

Comment: u mean like that `? Container()
                : Image.file(_image != null).toCenter())` because this gives me an error

Comment: You already have null checks, just change one line. I'm updating my answer, check it out.

Comment: thanks, but if I did that , I'll get an error : Error: The argument type 'File?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'File' because 'File?' is nullable and 'File' isn't.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a boolean to check if _image has been initialized:

```
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  late File _image;
  bool _isImageInitialized = false;

  Future<void> getimageditor() =>
      Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
        return ImageEditorPro(
          appBarColor: Colors.black87,
          bottomBarColor: Colors.black87,
          pathSave: null,
        );
      })).then((geteditimage) {
        if (geteditimage != null) {
          setState(() {
            _image = geteditimage;
            _isImageInitialized = true;
          });
        }
      }).catchError((er) {
        print(er);
      });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return condition(
            condtion: _isImageInitialized == false,
            isTrue: 'Open Editor'.text().xRaisedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                getimageditor();
              },
            ).toCenter(),
            isFalse:
                Image.file(_image).toCenter())
        .xScaffold(
            appBar: 'Image Editor Pro example'.xTextColorWhite().xAppBar(),
            floatingActionButton:
                Icons.add.xIcons().xFloationActiobButton(color: Colors.red));
  }
}
```

Comment: gave me same error!